# C# Generics boxing errors

Tags: c#

I have the following code that worked before I changed to use generics for the service:

**Update:** I added some more class and interface info in response to comments:

```
public class Service<T1,T2> : BaseService, IService<T1>
        where T1 : IAuditableTable
        where T2 : IAuditableTable
{
    private IAzureTable<T1> _T1repository;
    private IAzureTable<T2> _T2repository;

    public Service(string ds)
    {
        base.Initialize(ds);
        _T1repository = StorageHelper.GetTable<T1>(ds);
        _T2repository = StorageHelper.GetTable<T2>(ds);
    }

    public IEnumerable<AdminDetail> ShowDetails()
    {
        return base.ShowDetails(_T1repository, _T2repository);
    } 

    ...
```

and

```
public IEnumerable<AdminSummary> ShowSummary<T1, T2>(
        IAzureTable<T1> master, IAzureTable<T2> detail)
    where T1 : AuditableTable
    where T2 : AuditableTable
{
    ...

public abstract class AuditableTable : TableServiceEntity, IAuditableTable  
{
    ...

public interface IAzureTable<T> : IInitializer

public interface IService<T>
        where T : IAuditableTable
    {
        IEnumerable<AdminSummary> ShowSummary();
    }

private IService<Account> _account;
vm.AdminSummaries = _account.ShowSummary(); << calls the report
```

When I try to compile I get the following message:

> The type 'T2' cannot be used as type parameter 'T2' in the generic type or 
>   method 'Services.BaseService.ShowSummary<T1,T2>(AzureToolkit.IAzureTable<T1>, AzureToolkit.IAzureTable<T2>)'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T2' to 'Storage.Models.AuditableTable'.

Comment: What is the signature of your `IAzureTable<T>` interface?

Comment: Is ShowSummary<T1, T2> a member of Service<T1,T2> ?

Comment: @dtb: The compile error says it's a member of the base class `BaseService`.

Comment: public interface IAzureTable<T> : IInitializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need the `class` constraint on `T2`.

Comment: I added some more information to the question. Does this help explain? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `ShowSummary` needs types of `AuditableTable` (which does implement `IAuditableTable`). You supply values of just `IAuditableTable` where it needs the concrete class. The other way around (concrete implementation in parameter of interface type) would probably work.

Comment: Some more details added to the question